# Get last index number in dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

I've got this dataframe here:

```
print(df)

     symbol           Time        
0   AAA  1665597936065  
1   AAA  1665597951038  
3   AAA  1665597981219
```

and I want to get the index number for the last one

```
  3
```

I tried all combinations with df.index, df.index(), df.last_valid_index, and combinations of .tail(1) and .iloc[-1], df['index'] but not getting the actual index number!

Is it possible to get the index number at all?

Comment: `df.index[-1]` 
for example?

Answer (score 1):

Hi| You can also achieve it with iloc like you were trying for but the best way is how @AloneTogether said but I will leave here the iloc way too.

```
df.iloc[-1].name
```

this would result in 3